# Nested Datatables Single Row Selection

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have multiple datatables whose are in single selection mode. I know how many datatables I have and how to reference to them because I append an index to their widgetVar attribute. So I can reference them by the "non-safe" operation `var dt = eval('dt' + index)`.

The issue I am facing is every time I select a row in one of the nested dataTables the selection is remaining on the other ones and I want to clean them.

I've tried something like:

```xml
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" onstart="deseleccionarTablas()"/>
```

```js
function deseleccionarTablas()
{
     for (i=0; i < dtEstacionesSeleccionadas.getPaginator().cfg.rows; i++)
     { 
          var dt = eval('dt' + i);
          dt.unselectAllRows(); 
     }
};
```

dtEstacionesSeleccionadas is the "container" or "root" table and works in "lazy" mode with paginator, so a variable number of nested dataTables may be shown. The code above doesn't work because it unselects everything, even the last row I selected, as expected. And I want that last one to remain selected.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using JavaScript, why don't you update them on the server side? Each table should have the `selection="#{mrBean.selectedRow}"` attribute. You only need to set all of those things to `null` in the `actionListener` of the `<p:ajax event="rowSelect">`. Then, a simple `update="table1 table2 ... tablen"` will solve you problem.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for spend your time answering. That approximation is hard since I have my nested tables into a "lazy" root table and the count of displayed tables may vary -_I will edit my Question with this info_- so I can't define the update attr in a static way, and I guess It couldn't be set dynamically.